# SQL match against query giving unpredictable results

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to run the following search query in my database:

```
User::selectRaw("*, MATCH(first_name, last_name)AGAINST(?)", [$search_string])
            ->whereRaw("MATCH(first_name, last_name)AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", [$search_string])
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();
```

This works fine for a couple of times (sometimes only one time) and then I get the error `InvalidArgumentException: Inf and NaN cannot be JSON encoded in file`
This error is temporarely resolved when adding a new user to the database, but quickly returns after some tries with running the query. I think it has to do with the value being returned by the query. This value is sometimes `inf`. Why is this query behaving in such an unpredictable manner?

Comment: "Why is this query behaving in such an unpredictable manner?" it's not the query i more believe Laravel querybuilder is the blame of this.. i also want to bet that if you try the generated/written SQL directly on the database it will work every time.

Comment: Oh you're right! Thanks for pointing in the right direction, I will try to find out what's going wrong in Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by replacing the selectRaw statement by a raw statement, like this:

```
User::raw("SELECT * FROM MATCH(first_name, last_name)AGAINST(?)", [$search_string])
            ->whereRaw("MATCH(first_name, last_name)AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", [$search_string])
            ->limit(10)         
            ->get();
```